# Print Output of Loop to Individual File Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have this code:

```
ipaddr = input("Enter IP Address: ")
devicename = input ("Enter Device Name: ")

for i, d in zip(ipaddr.split(), devicename.split()):
   print("Your IP is: ", i, "Your device is: ", d)
```

My output is this:

```
Enter IP Address: 1 2 3 4 5

Enter Device Name: d1 d2 d3 d4 d5

Your IP is:  1 Your device is:  d1
Your IP is:  2 Your device is:  d2
Your IP is:  3 Your device is:  d3
Your IP is:  4 Your device is:  d4
Your IP is:  5 Your device is:  d5
```

I would like each line above (IP and device name combination) to be saved into individual txt files like this:

```
C:\Scripts
d1.txt
d2.txt
d3.txt
d4.txt
d5.txt
```

I am looking into creating another program to read those files individually some other time. For now I am looking into saving my output into different files. Hoping you could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, You can add a variable in string with the following syntax:

```
variable=33
a="%s"%variable
print(a)
```

output will be:

```
'33'

ipaddr = input("Enter IP Address: ")
devicename = input ("Enter Device Name: ")

for i, d in zip(ipaddr.split(), devicename.split()):
   print("Your IP is: ", i, "Your device is: ", d)
   with open("%s.txt"%d,"w")as file: #opens a file with value of d.txt as file name to write
        file.write("Your IP is: %s Your device is %s"%(i,d))
```

Comment: This worked like a charm sir. Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

All you realistically have to add is file creation to your loop, as follows:

```
for i, d in zip(ipaddr.split(), devicename.split()):
     with open("d%d.txt"%i, "w") as fp:
          fp.write("Your IP is: ", i, "Your device is: ", d)
```